# Sync Quickbooks desktop and quickbooks payments against that invoice

Tags: php, payment, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to send an email of the invoice with a payment link from the QuickBooks desktop, is there any API for it? and once the payment capture need to sync on Quickbooks desktop and Quickbooks Payments against the invoice.

I can able to add the customer and create an invoice by using QuickBooks desktop API. Still, I want to send an email of the invoice with a payment link from the QuickBooks desktop and once the payment is captured, I need to add the payment receive entry against the invoice and sync QuickBooks payment and Quickbooks desktop.